# How to get rid of unwanted thick vertical lines in tabular environment?

Tags: tables, floats

So I have this code, which produces a table that I'm happy with, except for these thick vertical lines:

[image]

As you can see, the thickness of the vertical lines separating the columns doesn't match the thickness of the horizontal lines.

I'd like the vertical lines and the horizontal lines to have the same thickness. ¿How do I do this?

```
\begin{table}[h]
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{ |p{4cm}|p{4cm}|p{4cm}|p{4cm}| }
 \hline
 \multicolumn{4}{|c|}{\textbf{Grupo motopropulsor}} \\ 
 \hline
 Número & \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{2} & \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{B737} & \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{A220/Bombardier Serie C} \\
 \hline
 Posición & \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{Bajo las alas} & \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{Boeing} & \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{Airbus/Bombardier} \\
 \hline
 Tipo & \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{Turbofán} & \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{-} & \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{-} \\
 \hline
 Modelo & \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{CFM56-5B5/P} & \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{-} & \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{-} \\
 \hline
 Fabricante & \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{CFM International} & \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{-} & \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{-} \\
 \hline
 Peso \footnotemark[2] $W_{eng}$ (kg) & \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{2381} & \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{-} & \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{-} \\
 \hline
 Empuje máximo en crucero \footnotemark[3] $T_{eng}$ (kN) & \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{22.33} & \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{-} & \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{-} \\
 \hline
 Consumo específico en crucero \footnotemark[3] $c_e$ (mg/Ns) & \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{16.98} & \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{-} & \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{-} \\
 \hline
 Empuje total de despege $T_{to}$ (kN) & \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{199.58} & \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{-} & \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{-} \\
 \hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{Grupo motopropulsor.}
\label{cuadro_3}
\end{center}
\end{table}
```

Comment: Don't use `\multicolumn{|c|}{<stuff>}` but instead `\multicolumn{c|}{<stuff>}`. You get two adjacent lines the way your code currently is, and that looks like one thicker line.

Comment: As an aside, don't use the `center` environment inside of `table`, that gives unwanted extra space. Instead just use `\centering` at the beginning of the `table` environment.

Comment: Do you really need to repeat \multicolumn{1}{|c|} before every cell entry, due to used packages?

Comment: Note that your table is a bit atypical. It doesn't contain column heads, so I have no idea which column describes what (and to worsen it, I don't speak Spanish...). So your table could get a more thorough overhaul and might look better afterwards. Maybe you should read an introduction to tables in LaTeX, take a look for example here: https://www.learnlatex.org/es/lesson-08

Comment: @C.Peters I think that is because of the `p{4cm}` specification in the top level.

Comment: You should remove all the \multicolumn{1} specifications they are doing nothing useful, just specifuy the format for the column once in teh argument to tabular

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The original problem is that you're including a vertical rule at the start and end of each cell by using `\multicolumn{1}{|c|}`, instead better would be to use only one vertical rule at the end of each column to only have one rule instead of two adjacent ones. But the `\multicolumn` isn't necessary at all here:

The following is your table with a few changes:

- No need for `\multicolumn` if you use the alignment type for the entire column (your table used `p{4cm}` for each column, and then went on to use `\multicolumn{|c|}{<stuff>}` in *every* row of those columns to get centred material, better to just use the `c` type to get a centred column)
- I've removed the first line, that one is just the same as the table caption, why do you need that information twice?
- I put the `\label` inside the argument of `\caption`, that is the best practice (though after the caption works most of the time, it isn't absolutely safe everytime and might result in inconsistent spacing), you just have to watch out not to accidentally include an unwanted space before or after the `\label` this way.
- no `center` environment inside of the `table`, instead use `\centering`
- I've used the `array` package to define the column type `L` that works just like a `p`-column, but doesn't fully justify the text, instead left aligns it. That tends to look better inside narrow columns like this one.

What I didn't fix in this answer is that your table is wider than the text area (at least in `article`). If you have a wider text block this should be no problem, if the text block is as narrow as the standard in `article` you'll have to fix this.

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{#1}}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[h]
  \centering
  \begin{tabular}{ |L{4cm}|c|c|c| }
   \hline
   Número & 2 & B737 & A220/Bombardier Serie C \\
   \hline
   Posición & Bajo las alas & Boeing & Airbus/Bombardier \\
   \hline
   Tipo & Turbofán & - & - \\
   \hline
   Modelo & CFM56-5B5/P & - & - \\
   \hline
   Fabricante & CFM International & - & - \\
   \hline
   Peso \footnotemark[2] $W_{eng}$ (kg) & 2381 & - & - \\
   \hline
   Empuje máximo en crucero \footnotemark[3] $T_{eng}$ (kN) & 22.33 & - & - \\
   \hline
   Consumo específico en crucero \footnotemark[3] $c_e$ (mg/Ns) & 16.98 & - & - \\
   \hline
   Empuje total de despege $T_{to}$ (kN) & 199.58 & - & - \\
   \hline
  \end{tabular}
  \caption{Grupo motopropulsor.\label{cuadro_3}}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Great answer. I noticed I have the problem of the table being larger than the text area. How do I go about fixing that?

Comment: @stevederekson555 easiest way would be to reduce the width of the first and last column, you could try to use `\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}` in your preamble and then use `C{4cm}` for a 4cm wide column that is centred (just like the `L` type column). Or you could reduce the font size using e.g. `\small` just before `\begin{tabular}`. You can take search for "table too wide" on this site, this should yield a few questions with this problem and ways how to fix this.

Comment: Your first bullet seems to imply that `\multicolumn` is unnecessary/wasteful, but other answers suggest (I know almost nothing about TeX) that it is actually the cause of the problem that the question asks after. Emphasizing that before getting into all of your other (wonderful!) suggestions would improve this answer, since as a TeX noob I had no idea if or how you had answered the question.

Comment: @KRyan it is both in this case (note that many the comments saying that `\multicolumn` is the root here are from me). `\multicolumn` is handy, but it is wrong design to use it in every cell. The real root of the issue is the second argument of `\multicolmn` being `|c|`, meaning one rule before and one rule after the current column. If this is used in consecutive columns you'll get two rules there, one as after the first cell, one as before the second.

Comment: I understand that both are the case—but your answer only indicates one, not both. There is nothing in your answer (alone) which would tell a reader that removing `\multicolumn` solves the problem in the question. Since that was the question, any answer to it *must* address that point explicitly.

Comment: @KRyan though I don't agree completely, point taken, paragraph added.

Comment: Vastly improved, +1, and thank you for putting up with me.

Answer (score 4):

They look the same when I magnified the pdf file:
[image]

Comment: They don't if you load the `array` package. The underlying problem is that there are two adjacent lines (without the `array` package they don't take up any space, so are completely overlapping, with `array` this changes and they become twice as thick). The underlying problem is the usage of `\multicolumn{|c|}` in every column.